# firebase server Authenticate with admin privileges

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I am trying to setup firebase server using nodejs as discussed [Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/server/start). However my code is not able to read or wite data from/to any tables using admin privileges even the ones with public read and write access.

This is my code from the server side:

```
var firebase = require('firebase');
firebase.initializeApp({
serviceAccount: "./App.json",
databaseURL: "https://userPosts.firebaseio.com"
});
//
var db = firebase.database();
var ref = db.ref("testPosts");

ref.once("value", function(snapshot){
    console.log(snapshot.val());
}, function(error){
    console.log(error);
});
```

The code below is how the security is set on the server:

```
"rules": {
  "users": {
    "$uid": {
      ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid",
      ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid"
    }
  },
"testPosts": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

If I comment the serviceAccount line on the server side, the data will be read with no issue and access will be denied when I try to access a node that it does not have access ( which is normal behaviour).

My understanding of Firebase admin privileges is that I should have access to all table nodes regardless of the access privilege.

I would really appreciate if someone can help with this issue. I have been stuck on it for a while now.

-----------------------Edit----------------

I have enabled debugging by adding

```
firebase.database.enableLogging(true);
```

and I get the following error:

```
p:0: Listen called for /posts default
p:0: Making a connection attempt
p:0: Failed to get token: Error: Error refreshing access token:     invalid_grant (Invalid JWT: Token must be a short-lived token and in a reasonable timeframe)
p:0: data client disconnected
p:0: Trying to reconnect in 77.64995932509191ms
0: onDisconnectEvents
```

Can anybody help with the error and what it really means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some diggings, it appears that my server time was the problem. 
The time of my server was not in sync with the [Network Time Protocol (NTP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol).

In case someone is experiencing the same issue, the following [link](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/authorization#invalid_grant) can be useful.

Comment: Razor, one question please.
In the App.json file, what do you have? Your credentials like, email and password?
Thanks!

Comment: the app.json is the file generated from the firebase console. it contains fields like project id, private key, client email and many more. the ppassword is not included